# Erro ao fazer requisição HTTP android

Tags: android, http, http-request

Estou implementando um app android nativo que faz requisição com um WS. Ao tentar fazer a conexão no método `connect()` de `HttpURLConnection` estou recebendo um erro que não cai no `catch` para ser validado.

Fazendo algumas pesquisas descobri que o erro se dá pela porta que informei na minha URL de conexão pois o meu servidor é local. Setei a porta de número 80886 por exemplo. Com isso recebi o erro `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port=80886`. Pesquisando mais um pouco entendi que o numero máximo de portas aceitas é de 65535 e de fato se eu colocar a porta 65536 recebo o mesmo erro mencionado anteriormente, uma porta menor não da problemas.

Até aqui é até compreensível pois vi que tem ligação com os protocolos TCP e esse número mágico 65535 na verdade é o número máximo já que é o cálculo de 2^16. Como os identificadores de porta são inteiros de 16 bits, esse o valor máximo aceito.

Fiz o teste utilizando 2 aparelhos distintos. Um com a versão 4.4.4 do android e outro com a versão 8.0.0. No dispositivo com a versão 4.4.4 ocorreu o erro, já no android 8.0.0 não tive problemas.

Saberiam me explicar o motivo disso acontecer? 
Por que ocorre erro apenas na versão antiga?

**Código do Método:**

```
public static boolean testarConexaoServidor(String url) {

    boolean retorno = false;
    int milissegundos = 20000;

    try {
        URL apiEnd = new URL(url);
        int codigoResposta;
        HttpURLConnection conexao;

        conexao = (HttpURLConnection) apiEnd.openConnection();
        conexao.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conexao.setReadTimeout(milissegundos);
        conexao.setConnectTimeout(milissegundos);
        conexao.connect();

        codigoResposta = conexao.getResponseCode();
        if (codigoResposta < HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST) {
            retorno = true;         
        }

        conexao.disconnect();


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return retorno;
}
```

Comment: Código... Se poder, claro

Comment: Inserido na pergunta para melhor facilidade de entendimento e leitura. Obrigado Woton. E para ratificar, o erro ocorre assim que a linha "conexao.connect();" é processada. Não passa dela e da erro fatal no app nas versões 4.4 do android. Não testei em anteriores. Na 6.0 e 8.0 funcionou corretamente.

Comment: Qual é exatamente a pergunta? Não existe porta TCP nem UDP com número acima de 65535, então o motivo do erro já está claro.

Comment: Desculpe se não ficou claro a pergunta. O que queria saber é por que acontece o erro "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port=80886", causando erro fatal na aplicação apenas na versão 4.4 do android e não nas versões 6.0 ou 8.0?